# How to make a pandas crosstab with percentages?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Given a dataframe with different categorical variables, how do I return a cross-tabulation with percentages instead of frequencies?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three'] * 6,
                   'B' : ['A', 'B', 'C'] * 8,
                   'C' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'] * 4,
                   'D' : np.random.randn(24),
                   'E' : np.random.randn(24)})


pd.crosstab(df.A,df.B)


B       A    B    C
A               
one     4    4    4
three   2    2    2
two     2    2    2
```

Expected output:

```
B       A     B    C
A               
one     .33  .33  .33
three   .33  .33  .33
two     .33  .33  .33
```

Comment: Wouldn't you expect the table to be `0.167 0.167 0.167\n 0.083 0.083 0.083\n 0.083 0.083 0.083`?

Comment: I guess you want specifically the "percent within row" (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crosstab).

Comment: In Pandas 0.18.1, it looks like you can pass normalize="index" to divide each entry into the row's sum .

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
pd.crosstab(df.A, df.B).apply(lambda r: r/r.sum(), axis=1)
```

Basically you just have the function that does `row/row.sum()`, and you use `apply` with `axis=1` to apply it by row.

(If doing this in Python 2, you should use `from __future__ import division` to make sure division always returns a float.)

Comment: You'd need a `from __future__ import division` to force floating point division on integers.

Comment: That's true.  I added that to my answer.  (I have my shell set to do this automatically so I always forget it needs to be done.)

Comment: @BrenBarn
What is the importance of axis=1 here..!? really not able to understand..!

Comment: @Rohith: Not sure what you don't understand.  As I said in my answer, axis=1 applies the function *by row*.  Otherwise the percentages would be computed relative to the column totals rather than the row totals.

Answer (score 110):

From Pandas 0.18.1 onwards, there's a `normalize` option:

```
In [1]: pd.crosstab(df.A,df.B, normalize='index')
Out[1]:

B              A           B           C
A           
one     0.333333    0.333333    0.333333
three   0.333333    0.333333    0.333333
two     0.333333    0.333333    0.333333
```

Where you can normalise across either `all`, `index` (rows), or `columns`.

More details are available [in the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html).

Comment: A benefit of this option is that it still works if you include marginal subtotals.

Answer (score 19):

We can show it as percentages by multiplying by `100`:

```
pd.crosstab(df.A,df.B, normalize='index')\
    .round(4)*100

B          A      B      C
A                         
one    33.33  33.33  33.33
three  33.33  33.33  33.33
two    33.33  33.33  33.33
```

Where I've rounded for convenience.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a percentage of the total, you can divide by the len of the df instead of the row sum:

```
pd.crosstab(df.A, df.B).apply(lambda r: r/len(df), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Normalizing the index will simply work out. Use parameter, `normalize = "index"` in `pd.crosstab()`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [div](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) rather than apply:

```
In [11]: res = pd.crosstab(df.A, df.B)
```

Divide by the sum over the index:

```
In [12]: res.sum(axis=1)
Out[12]: 
A
one      12
three     6
two       6
dtype: int64
```

*Similar to above, you need to do something about integer division (I use astype('float')):*

```
In [13]: res.astype('float').div(res.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
Out[13]: 
B             A         B         C
A                                  
one    0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
three  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
two    0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
```